# How to draw a string at an exact pixel position

Tags: c#, .net, graphics, bitmap, drawstring

I try to draw a string (single character) in C# into a Bitmap at an exact position with:

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(64, 64);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
g.DrawString("W", font1, new SolidBrush(myColor), new Point(32,32);
```

There is so much empty space rendered around a single letter, that I can not guess the "needed" position to draw the character to have it at the correct position at the end.

By now I have the pixel exact dimension of the character (looking at bits in a separately rendered bitmap). But this information is useless, if I cannot draw the character at an exact position (e.g. center or top right corner or ....).

Are there other methods to draw text in C# on a bitmap? Or are there any converting methods to convert the real pixel position in something DrawString needs?

Comment: Are you looking for Graphics.MeasureString/MEasureCharRanges which will calculate the bounding rectangle?

Comment: Would it help you to [measure the string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/6xe5hazb.aspx) before drawing it?

Comment: You can get the measurement of all pixels using a GraphicsPath. But it will not tell you just where this bounding box is in the DrawString's bounding box. So maybe you need to actually use the GP itself..

Comment: I know the exact pixel dimension of the character by rendering it in an extra bitmap and examine all pixels ... but what does it helps, if I know a "W" is 12x23 pixel when I cannot draw it in the middle of a given rectangle.

Comment: Well just offset the draw origin by half the glyph width/height

Comment: `innerRectangle.Top = (outerRectangle.Height - innerRectangle.Height) / 2; innerRectangle.Left = (outerRectangle.Width - innerRectangle.Width) / 2;`

Comment: Nope ... the character itself is not drawn at the position itself ... there is an offset of some pixel from the top left corner (I define to draw it) and the final position it is drawn.

Comment: You could copy the pixels from your 'extra' bitmap after you've examined all of the pixels.  You could also design your own 'font' and rasterize the characters yourself.

Comment: Another method would be [TextRenderer.MeasureText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/y4xdbe66.aspx) -- this returns slightly different values. Maybe more to what you want. Needs a reference to Windows.Forms.

Comment: Have you resolved your problems?

Comment: @Konrad - the point that Alex and Corak make, is that once you know the offset between the bounding ("outer") rectangle, and the non blank pixels ("inner rectangle), you can *compensate* for that offset. However, Corak gave the wrong formula. Given blank widths `LM/TM/RM/BM` (left/top/right/bottom margin): To position the *upper-left corner*: `pos.X -= LM; pos.Y -= TM`. To correct a *center* placement (assuming you've already adjusted `pos` to center): `pos.X -= (LM-RM)/2; pos.Y -= (TM-BM)/2;`

Answer (score 5):

No need to look at the pixels or start working with your own font..

You can use a `GraphicsPath` instead of `DrawString` or `TextRenderer`, as it will let you know its **net bounds rectangle** with `GraphicsPath.GetBounds()` .

When you know it, you can calculate how to move the `Graphics` object using `TranslateTransform`:

[image]

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string text = "Y";                  // whatever
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(64, 64);    // whatever
    bmp.SetResolution(96, 96);          // whatever
    float fontSize = 32f;               // whatever

    using ( Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    using ( GraphicsPath GP = new GraphicsPath())
    using ( FontFamily fontF = new FontFamily("Arial"))
    {
        testPattern(g, bmp.Size);      // optional

        GP.AddString(text, fontF, 0, fontSize, Point.Empty,
                     StringFormat.GenericTypographic);
        // this is the net bounds without any whitespace:
        Rectangle br = Rectangle.Round(GP.GetBounds());

        g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red,br); // just for testing

        // now we center:
        g.TranslateTransform( (bmp.Width - br.Width )  / 2 - br.X,
                              (bmp.Height - br.Height )/ 2 - br.Y);
        // and fill
        g.FillPath(Brushes.Black, GP);
        g.ResetTransform();
    }

    // whatever you want to do..
    pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
    bmp.Save("D:\\__test.png", ImageFormat.Png);

}
```

A small test routine to let us see the centering better:

```
void testPattern(Graphics g, Size sz)
{
    List<Brush> brushes = new List<Brush>() 
    {   Brushes.SlateBlue, Brushes.Yellow, 
        Brushes.DarkGoldenrod, Brushes.Lavender };
    int bw2 = sz.Width / 2;
    int bh2 = sz.Height / 2;
    for (int i = bw2; i > 0; i--)
        g.FillRectangle(brushes[i%4],bw2 - i, bh2 - i, i + i, i + i );

}
```

The `GetBounds` method returns a `RectangleF`; in my example it is `{X=0.09375, Y=6.0625, Width=21, Height=22.90625}`. Do note that due to rounding things can always be off by one..

You may or may not want to change the `Graphics` setting to special `Smoothingmodes` etc..

Also it should be noted that this will do automatic ie mechanical centering by the bounds rectangle. This may be quite different from ['optical or visual centering'](http://www.fonts.com/content/learning/fontology/level-2/display-typography/display-margins-centering), which is rather hard to code and to some extent a matter of personal taste. But typography is as much an art as a profession..